# Mongodb equivalent of RIGHT JOIN - Data may be in collection A or B, should I combine collections or lookup twice?

Tags: mongodb, data-structures, mongodb-query, datamodel

I'm new to MongoDB, coming from a SQL background

I have two collections of orders:

- A: Includes payments made using a website
- B: Includes payments made using an app

I want to summarise data for customers and the issue i'm facing is that I can't simply do lookup since some customers will only use B ever, so they'll be excluded

What would be the best way to do this?

I'm hesitant to create a brand new collection, embedding A and B, at the customer level since that'll be duplicating data and space is an important consideration

---

Here is a sample of A and B:

A (website):

```
{
"_id": 1,
customer_id: 2,
order_id: 1188,
date: "2018/06/01",
item_id: "1",
item_name: "Item 1",
amount_paid: 30
}
```

B (app):

```
{
"_id": 12,
customer_id: 2,
order_id: 1247,
date: "2018/04/01",
item_id: "2",
item_name: "Item 2",
amount_paid: 8
},
{
"_id": 13,
customer_id: 4,
order_id: 2532,
date: "2018/08/02",
item_id: "2",
item_name: "Item 2",
amount_paid: 8
}
```

---

Important note: The vast majority of orders are made using website (A)

What would be the best practice here?

---

Basic questions i'm trying to answer:

"How many orders are there for customer x?" where x could have used (A and B) or (A or B)

---

Expected output:

```
{
"_id": 1,
customer_id: 2,
order_id: 1188,
date: "2018/06/01",
item_id: "1",
item_name: "Item 1",
amount_paid: 30
},
{
"_id": 12,
customer_id: 2,
order_id: 1247,
date: "2018/04/01",
item_id: "2",
item_name: "Item 2",
amount_paid: 8
},
{
"_id": 13,
customer_id: 4,
order_id: 2532,
date: "2018/08/02",
item_id: "2",
item_name: "Item 2",
amount_paid: 8
}
```

In the expected output you can see that all customer_id 2 had both orders from A and B, and customer_id 4 (that didn't appear in A) was also included

---

MongoDB version - 4.0.1

---

Thanks in advance

Comment: I was thinking that I might create a customers collection comprised of purely the distinct customer_ids. Then i'd lookup to A and B from customers and join the records against the customer_id. Thoughts?

Comment: what should be the expected output?... Please clarify your question more and mention your mongodb version

Comment: @AnthonyWinzlet thanks for taking the time to review, i've updating my question with the desired output and db version

Comment: why `customer_id` with 4? and from where you would like to start the aggregation (from customer)? have you tried something?

Comment: I'd like to basically outer join A with B, leaving my with the list of orders made by customers on the app(A) and the website (B). Reason for outer join is that some customers only purchase on the app, and so lookup from A to B would exclude these. Later I would aggregate this to answer questions like "How many purchases did customer_id 2 make?"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out I can simply do this:

```
db.B.find().forEach (
    function(x) {
        db.A.insert(x)
        } )
```

And what this does is "for every document in B, insert as a new document into collection A"